# responsive image list with images in different sizes

Tags: html, css, image, list, menu

I started to learn responsive webdesign but now I have a little Problem:
My Navigation is a list with images where every image has a different width.
Here is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/yxLLncpb/

If I use the same size for every image it works and if the window gets smaller, the picture get smaller, too.

But I gave every image a individual size like here:

```
ul li#home{width:7,53%;}
ul li#vermeldungen{width:18,59%;}
ul li#tup{width:20,83%;}
ul li#ug{width:22,59%;}
ul li#kirchen{width:8,79%;}
```

And now If I resize the window the images keep their size :/
Could anyone tell me, why the images doesn't resize, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ul li#home{width:7.53%;}
ul li#vermeldungen{width:18.59%;}
ul li#tup{width:20.83%;}
ul li#ug{width:22.59%;}
ul li#kirchen{width:8.79%;}
```

you have used comma mistakenly, but need to use dot

```
<li id="kirchen"><img src="http://www.georgs-kirche.de/wordpress/wp-content/themes/georgtheme/images/nav_kirchen.png"></li>
```

Last item you have used `class` but need to change `id`

Check the working [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/yxLLncpb/1/)

Answer (score 0):

here is the working fiddle

```
ul li#home{
width:7,53%;
}
```

change to

```
ul li#home{
width:7.53%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yxLLncpb/2/